# Ethernet port won't detect cable if it was plugged before boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot, drivers, ethernet

I'm having trouble connecting a computer to the internet. I am able to do it only if I follow the steps below (which is not a desired behavior), and I need help to make it work properly.

---

**THE PROBLEM**

It is happening on a computer that its intended to be used like an amateur's server.

The physical port will only detect the cable if I follow these steps:

- disconnect the eth cable.
- reboot the computer.
- wait the os to load.
- plug the cable.

If I don't follow these steps, the computer won't recognize the cable, and it will not be able to reconnect to internet. The LED's on the physical port won't turn on, and the result of `sudo ethtool eth0 | grep Link` will be `Link detected: no`

This problem is specially bothering since it's supposed to be a 'server'.

---

**MY THOUGHTS AND QUESTIONS**

I'm thinking it might be a driver problem (and I just hope this is not a hardware issue). I don't really know what to do next.

How can I debug this kind of problems any further?

Is there a tool to look for updated drivers (a console tool would be preferable)?

Is there a work-arround I can use for the time being (like a cron resetting the interface if no ping to 8.8.8.8)?

---

**SYSTEM INFO**

The motherboard is an **Asus Z590-A PRO**

The eth interface is an **Intel® 2.5G Ethernet** The controller is **Intel Ethernet Controller I225-V (rev 03)**

The OS is **HiveOs 0.6-217@220510**, based on **Ubuntu 18.04**

---

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

I don't know when this problem started, since I bought the ethernet cable today. Before that I was working with an USB WIFI antenna, which wasn't great either.

I have not any other OS installed, nor a live USB to do testing. I'll have to wait to Monday for doing so.

The Eth cable is not the problem, I tested it on a router and my laptop, It worked on both.

Not sure if relevant, but I'm using netplan, which was't installed by default.
this is my `/etc/netplan/config.yml` file

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.x.y/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.x.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

(x and y are numbers)

I tagged "Ubuntu" since the OS is based on it and there is no tag for "hive"

---

**UPDATE**

I brought the computer to the office I work on, and there I don't have the problem.

I think it might have been the router.

I'll bring the computer back to the house next month or the month after that. Meanwhile I'll just leave it there.

I'll leave this question open so if the problem comes back when I bring the computer here, I can debug it properly, find the root cause, and leave here useful information for anyone who has this problem on the future.

Thank you all who have helped me here.

Comment: Have you checked with another cable? It is my understanding that the light at the female connector should go anyway. If it stays off, i could point to the cable, your port or the other devices port (try connecting to another one if possible). What does `/var/log/kern.log` say about the card, when it works and when it doesn't? Search around `igb` if you don't see anything.

Comment: This helps with my sometimes somewhat iffy ethernet setup: `modprobe -r driver; modprobe driver`, i.e. remove and then reinsert the ethernet module.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani kind of... The cable I bought is long (40 mts), I don't have another cable that can reach the place were that computer is located, but I tried plugging that cable to a router, and then using other cables from the router to both my laptop and that computer. Only the laptop worked, the other computer's behavior was the same I describe on the post. Plugging the same 40mt cable to my laptop also works without issue. So my guess is the female connector o some driver. I think it might be the driver because two main reasons (following comments)

Comment: 1) Because after ssh reboot, cable won't be detected, and that's odd since there's 0 chance the cable moves on that scenario

Comment: 2) Because unplugging / re-plugging wont work at all (no lights will go on) unless I reboot with the cable unplugged. After doing that, the cable is detected on the first try. (I didn't try unplugging / re-plugging with the cable working, I'll test that tomorrow)

Comment: @RudiC I will try that tomorrow, if it works, I'll notify you so you can answer this and I can accept that answer. Thanks